# Cannot load @font-face

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, webforms, font-face

I have custom font as you can see on the picture but it is never loaded and used on webpage. If I use commented line it works fine at all browsers but Internet Explorer (11). I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

[image: FontFace]

Answer (score 0):

You are using font which are not actually defined, 
it is nested in font-face property on line 1. 
Try to delete that font-face "wrapper" from line 1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, but that not helped.